# Use of similar logical file in Crystal Reports

Tags: ibm-midrange, crystal-reports-xi

I have a Crystal Report accessing Iseries 5 Physical or Logical files.  One of the Logicals, is sort has many data rows, it is based on the Order details. I copied this logical as a new one with new name. Only difference is I Omit most of the records according to a hard coded date.

Is there anything that should change in the Crystal report other than the name change of this logical. I am in the process of rebuilding the new one with this name. Some areas of concern with the crystal is some formulas which before were coded with the old name now of course they will have the new name. Is there any reason why this simple exercise should not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally should be no problem with either physical or logical files -just need to re-map your datasource. Goto 
Database > Set Datasouce Location. Select the table to change under Current Data Source,
 select the table to replace under Replace with -> then click Update.

If memory serves me right, formula will still works with rename fields - crystal reports somehow keep an alias name. Hope this helps